# How to install multiple vim color schemes in the same .vim directory?

Tags: git, vim, color-scheme

I'm new to Linux and using this guide https://opensource.com/article/19/12/colors-themes-vim to install my own color scheme for vim. The first color scheme works well with the given instructions. The problem occurred when I tried to install a second color scheme into the same .vim directory. I executed the same git clone command and was told that the directory was not empty (so clone was not successful at all). I created a new empty directory inside .vim then cloned but this time vim cannot find the cloned color scheme. I guess all color schemes have to be in the same .vim directory but git clone does not allow me to do that. Can anyone give some hint on what I should do? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question is not about programming and doesn't belong on SO. [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) or Vim SE would be better places to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming you are on Vim >= 8) First delete the directory you have made. Then create a plugin directory with

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start
```

Go to this directory and clone the color themes you want to use. Example:

```
cd ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start
git clone https://github.com/jnurmine/Zenburn.git
git clone https://github.com/Donearm/Laederon.git
```

At the same place you can clone the repos of all the other plugins you want to use.

Comment: Thank you so much Tekki! It's just amazing how your solution is more beginner-friendly than most guides on Google or YouTube:)

Answer (score 0):

Do `git clone` to any other folder and then copy the files to the folder you want